# 301 redirect on windows with ISAPI_Rewrite 3

Tags: iis, redirect

I have a page '/communities/communities.html' which i want to redirect to './communities.aspx"

my httpd.ini file looks like this but I cant get it to work. It just acts like there is no redirect.

```
redirect 301 /communities/communities.html http://www.thecondopros.com/communities.aspx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead in your site root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule communities/communities.html http://www.thecondopros.com/communities.aspx [R=302]
```

Also ISAPI_Rewrite3 defaults to naming the naming the rewrite rule file `.htaccess` and not `httpd.ini`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent a lot of time last night on this. google has tons on how to do all sorts of fancy things but I couldn't find how to do this in the way you just showed me and my host doesn't let me use the native IIS redirect features.

Answer (score 0):

or, the correct answer:

```
RewriteRule communities/communities.html http\://www.thecondopros.com/communities.aspx [I,R=301]
```

you probably want `I` to make it case insensitive, and you want `R=301`

have some docs: http://www.isapirewrite.com/docs/